# Audacity - Remove blank space on two track (3.1)

Tags: audacity

How do I remove any selected blank space on a track in Audacity 3.1.3 ?

Before, I could just select it and click backspace/delete/cut and it would work.

Now it only works if a track is part of the selection.

[image: selection to remove]

Answer (score 0):

Just left-click with your mouse on the top border of the adjacent clip. You get the hand symbol. Sometimes, it comes after pressing 'shift'. Drag the clip closer to the first clip. Similarly in all places where ypu have such dead blanks. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer but it did not solve my problem, which was an entire track preceded by a gap that had no sound - just time at the top, and rounded edges what was now the second track. I ended up grabbing (with the mouse, holding the left button down) the entire track and moving it. A yellow line showed when I was flush with 0 seconds.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/74910)

Comment: @Aaron I believe this does answer the question- "How do I remove any selected blank space" ... "it only works if a track is part of the selection."  I can't verify that it works, though, because I'm on a different version of Audacity.

Comment: @Edward "but it did not solve my problem."

Comment: I believe that is referring to the other answer posted by Ram, which he found before posting his own answer.